# My questions about HttpURLConnections on android. (cast-URLConnection, url.openConnection, getOutPutStream().. )

Tags: android, http-post, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I have a problem about creating a httpurlconnection(or httpsurlconnection). Actually this is about setting connection headers after casting url.openconnection.Before the running same code is not running now. I couldn't understand. (Exception  : already connected... or like.. )

Some times it runs until **httpConn.getOutPutStream();** At this time it gives error "java.net.ProtocolException: OutputStream unavailable because request headers have already been sent!"

Where is my fault??

Before I used code: All code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765524/what-difference-httpconnection-on-j2me-between-httpurlconnection-on-android-htt) (I have another questıon about [This Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765524/what-difference-httpconnection-on-j2me-between-httpurlconnection-on-android-htt), too)

```
URL url = new URL(getUrl());
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpConn=(HttpURLConnection)conn; /*or HttpsURLConnection*/
httpConn.set...
...
httpConn.connect();
...
```

I try to set some settings after casting , but result is same. conn.set..'s are working, but after casting I can't set anything...

Changed Code:

```
        URL url = new URL(getUrl());
        conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction",
                "http://tempuri.org/IAuthenticationServiceNew/Authenticate");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Software-Version", AppData.VERSION);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(getParams().getBytes("UTF8").length);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        httpConn.connect();
        os = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(getParams().getBytes("UTF8"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is right!
         "httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)" connects and sends headers to server. I close this code.

```
        URL url = new URL(getUrl());
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction",
                "http://tempuri.org/IAuthenticationServiceNew/"
                        + conTypeString);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Software-Version", AppData.VERSION);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        os = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(getParams().getBytes("UTF8"));
```